# Не приходит новый props в конструктор

Tags: reactjs

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой, не приходит новый `props` в `constructor` после изменения данных. За пределы `constructor` приходит новый `props`. Помогите пожалуйста. Объясните что делать)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        mode: 'product',
        items: this.props.items,
        models: this.props.models,
        itemsLoad: this.props.itemsLoad,
        modelsLoad: this.props.modelsLoad,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

При изменении свойств компонент заново не пересоздается, а значит и его конструктор не вызывается.

Самый простой вариант - не копировать свойства в состояние, а использовать их напрямую. Но если такой вариант вам недоступен - вам поможет метод [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    setState({
        items: newProps.items,
        models: newProps.models,
        itemsLoad: newProps.itemsLoad,
        modelsLoad: newProps.modelsLoad,
    })
}
```